# Need Help on regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I am Doing a Check on the JTextfield where i need input as

```
RD-AK+++++++ Or EX-AK+++++++
```

Its Total 12 characters `RD-AK or EX-AK` as a starting of the Alpha Numeric string.

Please Help me with regular Expression which will check for both the conditions.

Comment: What are the conditions you want to check for?

Comment: starting should be RD-AK or EX-AK

Comment: And the rest of the string could be any alphanumeric character?

Comment: What characters are accepltable after RD-AK/EX-AK?

Comment: @Keppil: Yes rest string could be any alphanumeric character and total length is 12 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps

```
input.matches("(RD|EX)-AK\\w{7}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match a string starting with either `RD-AK` or `EX-AK` followed by any seven characters.

```
/^(?:RD-AK|EX-AK).{7}$/
```

When you narrow your definition of "Alpha Numeric string" one can improve the "match-all" group. Say, you mean digits (0-9) an unspecial letters (a-z) you could try:

```
/^(?:RD-AK|EX-AK)[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

(RD|EX)-AK[A-Za-z0-9]{7}  is this what you wanted? test it here http://www.regexpal.com/